# Geting error while using $_POST to insert data to database

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I am trying to make a webapp using php. In that app i need to create Batch, Batch Subject etc. I have complited major part of this app. Althou it is working but i am geting an error notice like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: currentBatchId in C:\wamp64\www\sp\addBatchSubject.php on line 4
```

I have passed a batch Id from "batchview.php" page to add a batch subject using this code:

```
<a href="addBatchSubject.php?currentBatchId=<?php echo $s['batchId']; ?>">Add Subject</a>
```

By using the below code:

```
$currentBatchId=$_GET['currentBatchId'];
```

I can receive that value and can show in this page with out any problem. But while i want to add some data to the database using this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
```

While i press [add} button it generate the error Notice, but data inserted to the database successfully. Now i want to remove the error.
What is the wrong? while data insert code is posting the data to the database, Is the $_GET try to get another value ?
NB:  $_GET & $_POST are in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm following you right I think you need to switch the order of your code around..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    // handle adding new
    // make sure to header("Location: xxx.php"); to remove post data
    exit(); // because we don't need to continue
}

if(isset($_GET['currentBatchId'])) {
    $currentBatchId=$_GET['currentBatchId'];
}

// then maybe you also need to handle the no post / get request
if(!isset($_POST['add']) && !isset($_GET['currentBatchId'])) {
    // handle this case
    // maybe header("Location: blah.php");
    // maybe exit(); here too because we don't have enough information to render the page
}
```

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Hi Dale thanks a lot. I have rearranged the code as you said. the exit() works great. Thank you again.